# Moderator Pro Tempore

Tags: discussion, moderation

This community needs to contribute some names they would like to act as provisional Moderators, ASAP. **Most site have this discussion starting from the first days.** Please read this: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

Here are some basic guidelines:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity ([see this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/elect-our-provisional-moderators) for reference).
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

Here is what we are looking for in a Moderator...

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

Comment: Should this be on the main site or somehow linked to the site, to make it more visible to all users?

Answer (score 7):

I nominate **Vebjorn Ljosa**. He has been quite active on both [the regular](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/21/vebjorn-ljosa) and [the meta](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/21/vebjorn-ljosa) sites, trying to start the community here.

Also interesting is that he grew up in Norway and now lives in the US, which is useful on this site that might otherwise grow too specific to building practices in one country.

**Response:**

I accept the nomination, but with some reluctance.  I'll explain why.  This site has, at least so far, not had a real need for a moderator.  I don't think this will change over the next three months (unless the lawn-question controversy turns into an all-out barfight).  What we need most of all now is an influx of new users in order to bring the site to “critical mass,” i.e., the point where new users arrive spontaneously from Google in large enough numbers that the activity on the site becomes self-propagating.  If someone were really good at recruiting new users (e.g., via their blog, involvement on other DIY sites, or analog means), it would make sense for them to be moderators, to ensure that the community develops in a way that suits them.

I am embarassed to admin, in spite of all my talk on meta about recruiting new users, I have probably not recruited anyone to the site myself.  In contrast, [Jeff Widmer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/34/jeff-widmer) has posted on his [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2010/07/09/new-home-improvement-stackexchange-site-coming-soon.aspx), [Ryan Keeter](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/323/ryankeeter) and [Richard Tallent](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/165/richardtallent) have tweeted, and [Duncan Barnes](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/133/duncan) has posted on his blog.  Although it's hard to quantify the yield of the various recruiting attempts, these people (and others) have at least tried.

I have, however, been quite active in helping define the scope of the site.  Mostly by asking tons of questions I have as a new homeowner, but also by answering and commenting (and heckling on meta).  If people appreciate this activity and think it would be useful having me as a moderator, I'd be happy to wear a ♦ next to my name, at least for the duration of the beta.

Comment: Excellent candidate!

Answer (score 7):

[Eric Petroelje](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/44/eric-petroelje)

I'd be happy to do it.  Moderating as little as necessary, but no less :)

Comment: Good choice! Well-deserving of it.

Comment: This is payback for me nominating you isn't it? :)  In any case, I'll accept.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje: Not payback. You have the most rep, you are very active in the community, and you usually post the correct answer before anybody else even reads the question.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>[Scott Vercuski](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/45/scott-vercuski)</strike>

Declined.

Answer (score 3):

I'll nominate [Tester101](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/33/tester101)

I'll accept the nomination.

Comment: Excellent candidate!

Answer (score 2):

[Rod Fitzsimmons Frey](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/27/rod-fitzsimmons-frey)

Answer (score 1):

[Jeff Widmer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/34/jeff-widmer)

I accept the nomination.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I nominate **Mike Sherov**. He has been active on [the regular](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/57/mike-sherov) and [the meta](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/57/mike-sherov) sites, has [a good/high reputation on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260528/mike-sherov) and [participates in the meta discussions there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142597/mike-sherov). He is already a moderator on the Food and Cooking site (and [started the nominations](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280/moderator-nominations)).</strike>

Thanks for the nomination, but I respectfully decline.

Comment: thank you very much for the vote of confidence. I'm not sure I can be a very effective moderator given my current commitments to the other SE's I participate in. I will still be an active participant and give guidance and opinion, but I think it's important that others be allowed the chance to be recognized for their commitments. They usually choose four moderators, and I wouldn't want to take a valuable spot from a more deserving member on **this** SE. With that said, thanks again for the nomination, but I respectfully decline.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>[Joe](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/86/joe)</strike>

Declined due to previous Moderator appointment.

Comment: Thanks for the nomination, but I'm already a moderator on cooking, and don't think I'd have the time to contribute to both sites equally well.  I'll still contribute where I can.