# Can we delete duplicate/typo tags?

Tags: feature-request, maintenance

I was doing some cleanup and noticed a typo tag. (*plumbiing* instead of *plumbing*) I retagged the question, but the old typo tag is still there, even though no question uses it. Does this require mod attention, or will it just go away after a period of not being used? Or are we stuck with a *plumbiing* tag?

Comment: +1, even if it means no Taxonomist badge for me. :)  Well spotted and thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unused (or seldom-used) tags [will get deleted after six months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418). Moderators can also remove tags, so [elect them](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/moderator-pro-tempore)! Since you can't flag a tag for moderator attention, you could flag your own post, but I don't think the traffic on this meta site is so overwhelming your question will get buried otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

If there are no posts with the "plumbiing" tag it shouldn't get suggested as a possible tag after 24 hours.